# What is this logo? ☰M☰M☰ / ☰W☰W☰

Tags: identification, strain-gage

Seen on a strain gauge, and looks familiar, but I can't identify the manufacturer.  Who makes strain gauges with a logo consisting of:

- Two letter Ms (or maybe W if it is upside down)
- Three horizontal lines, passing behind the letters. or alternatively, stylised letter Es, so the logo reads EMEME

☰M☰M☰ or maybe ☰W☰W☰

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's likely [Micro Measurements](https://micro-measurements.com/linear-pattern-strain-gages).

They show a product like this:

[image: example product]

Found with: "Ememe strain gauge" picture search :D

Comment: I feel betrayed by google, it did not find that for me on the same search. Yes, that is it. Will give the green tick when the 15 minute timer runs out,.

Comment: "EMEME" worked with an image search? That is some sick algorithm voodoo... nice job!